# Calling a component by name in React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using the latest version of React Router 4.1.2 with dynamic routing.

This is working for me:

`routes.push(<Route key={tab.id} exact path="/" component={Dashboard}/>)`

But this is not working:

`routes.push(<Route key={tab.id} exact path="/" component={tab.component}/>)`

Obviously because `{tab.component}` is a string (with the value of `Dashboard`) where it `{Dashboard}` is a function.

How can I make it work? How do I turn my string into the React component with the same name as the string?

Comment: still not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve. The `component` prop accepts the component you want to render... why are you using dot notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way would be to place your components in a map so you can look them up by name. This is a very common pattern when you want to retrieve something via a string.

```
const componentByName = {
  Dashboard: <Dashboard />
};

routes.push(<Route 
  key={tab.id} 
  exact path="/" 
  component={componentByName[tab.component]}/>
);
```